# Watson dialog cURL conversation post request not passing form data

Tags: c#, curl, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

When making a post cURL request as below to try and continue a created conversation watson instead returns a new conversation.

```
curl -u "USERNAME":"PASSWORD" -X POST  --form conversation_id=CONVOID  --form client_id=CLIENTID  --form input="What type of toppings do you have?"  "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs/DIALOGID/conversation"
```

If i use the below cURL it works fine.

```
curl -u "USERNAME":"PASSWORD" --data "conversation_id=CONVOID&client_id=CLIENTID&input=What type of toppings do you have?" https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs/DIALOGID/conversation
```

My issue being that now when trying to write a c# wrapper i'm running in to the same issue that POST requests fail to transmit their form data correctly.

What's going on ?

I either need a c# MVC equivalent to the "`--data`" formatting. ( currently using `HttpClient.PostAsync`) or to figure out what is exactly wrong with using post requests to continue conversations.

As far as i can tell i am replicating the post request in c# correctly so i don't think there are two issues. ( just one post request issue, not a cURL issue then a C# implementation issue.)

For what it's worth i have left the commands in the format i submitted them, only replacing sensitive values with BLOCKCAPITALS. If it looks like i've missed a quotation mark or curly bracket , it's because i have and may be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service expects an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request

To do that in `curl` you need to use the `-d` parameter:

```
curl -u "USERNAME":"PASSWORD" -X POST 
  -d conversation_id=CONVOID 
  -d client_id=CLIENTID
  -d input="What type of toppings do you have?"
  "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs/DIALOGID/conversation"
```

> **-d, --data**
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.

Curl [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: That did it thanks! why do the IBM documentation list it as :
curl -u "{username}":"{password}" \
  -X POST
  --form conversation_id={conversation_id}
  --form client_id={client_id}
  --form input="Hi Hello"
  "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs/{dialog_id}/conversation"

Comment: I will make sure we fix that

Comment: Thank you! (Not to call you out but... ) there were i think 2 errors in the dialog example exercises as well. Is there a good place to forward these to? Also i have finished the c# wrapper and will be posting it to git soon, is this something that would be worth forwarding to you guys as well?

Comment: open an issue here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dialog-nodejs  I will make sure the team look at it