# Watson Curl Not Persisting / returning input

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

when I try to curl the following (obviously replaced the username, pw, and dialog id)

```
curl -u "username":"password" -X POST --form input="hi watson" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs/dialog-id/conversation"
```

I get

```
{"conversation_id":xxxxxx,"client_id":xxxxxx,"input": "","confidence":-1.0,"response":["Hi, I'm Watson! I can help you order a pizza, what size would you like?"]}
```

When I try to send another request with the appropriate client ID, conversation ID and new input it returns the same response with an empty input. When I run my xml in watson's dialog tool provided through github I get another answer.

From my understanding the input should show what I sent over. Any ideas why this is not getting processed?

Comment: I found this buried deep in some document from IBM 

curl -u <username>:<passwd> -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-WDC-PL-OPT-OUT: 1" -d
<payload_data> <service_url>

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685955/watson-dialog-curl-conversation-post-request-not-passing-form-data/35686112#35686112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685955/watson-dialog-curl-conversation-post-request-not-passing-form-data). I will write the same answer until we close this.

---

### Original Answer

The service expects an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request

To do that in curl you need to use the -d parameter:

```
curl -u "USERNAME":"PASSWORD" -X POST 
  -d conversation_id=conversation-id 
  -d client_id=client-id
  -d input="What type of toppings do you have?"
  "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs/dialog-id/conversation"
-d, --data
```

Make sure you replace the command with your credentials and `dialog-id`, `conversation-id` and `client-id`.

> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.